# customizing devise to update user attribute on signin and signout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a customer devise controller and i wan to set my sign up action to update a user status to online when the user signs in and off line when the users logout. I have

```
def signin
super
end
```

I want to update the users status attribute to online on login and offline on logout. Pls any help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be missing attr_accesible declaration for the "status" attribute of User table?

Answer (score -2):

You can use the after_sign_in_path_for and after_sign_out_path_for hooks provided in devise.  Just override those methods in your ApplicationController. Eg.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    #update user status to online
    root_path
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    #update user status to offline
    root_path
  end
end
```

More info here: [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-redirect-path-after-destroying-a-session-i.e.-signing-out)

Comment: i have tried and i cannot get the update_attributes to work. a simple help here

Comment: Can you show me your code.  Is your update code getting called? Is there an error?